# Between two dates splitting data into different rows?

Tags: ms-access

When I create a query in access and use `[forms]![frmmain]![txtfrom]` and `[forms]![frmmain]![txtto]` to choose to show data from a certain date if I choose two dates like 01/10/2012 to 08/10/2012 it splits the data out by date.

Is there anyway to merge all the dates into one?

Hi sorry here is what my query produces if it is between certain dates:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vR7Zn.png

I wanted to know if there was a way to merge all the dates into one when its the same person?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're question is a bit vague and confusing, but I believe what you are looking for is what Access refers to as a Totals query.  For example,

```
SELECT CategoryField, Sum(ValueField) AS SumOfValueField
FROM MyTable
WHERE DateField Between Forms!FrmMain!txtFrom And Forms!FrmMain!txtTo
GROUP BY CategoryField
```

You can create a "Totals query" in the Access query design window by clicking on the sigma (Σ) toolbar/ribbon button.  For more information, see here: [Sum data by using a query](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/sum-data-by-using-a-query-HA010096310.aspx)